# Как сделать что бы один акаунт мог использоваться только с одного и того же устройства

Tags: php, авторизация

Как сделать что бы один акаунт мог использоваться только с одного и того же устройства
Есть сайт хочу ограничить возможность входа в него только определенным устройствам ( по ip не подойдет поскольку у некоторых они динамические).
Сайт написан на php

Comment: вы уточните, это значит что я например зарегался на тлф,  и теперь только с тлф могу заходить, или что я не могу одновременно заходить с двух устройств?

Comment: Только с тлф и все

Comment: Ты знаешь как твой никнем переводится по казахски?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы "всегда с одного и того же устройства" - это в принципе нереализуемо, и надо забыть про такие фантазии.

Всё что можно сделать - это разлогинить автоматом все остальные клиенты, если пользователь зашёл с нового клиента. И кстати правильно говорить именно клиент. Потому что про устройства веб-сервер ничего не знает, и обращается к серверу именно клиент, а не "устройство".

А лучше всего задать вопрос воими словами, не употребляя непонятных для тебя терминов - какую задачу хочешь решить и зачем

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, зачем вам это нужно, но думаю что вам необходимо изучить вопрос цифрового отпечатка устройства (fingerprint)

[Цифровой отпечаток устройства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Но вообще, это могут расценивать как нарушение конфиденциальности пользователя.
Собрать фингерпринт браузера можно посредством js. Если не ошибаюсь, есть готовые библиотеки.

С ip,помимо той проблемы что описали вы, есть еще несколько. Например то, что с одного ip могут сидеть несколько разных устройств одного человека, или в принципе множество разных устройств. Например если все подключены к одному wifi.